# Is there a way to scroll an iFrame cross domain with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, scroll

I can't seem to find exactly what I want. Google keeps saying "position" (like CSS `top` and `left`), but what I want is to click a `button` and scroll a frame.

The point? So that I don't have to use scrollbars on frames--they can be ugly depending on what system you're using.

Comment: Ahh yes. Almost forgot:

If there's a way to do it cross domain please do tell.

Comment: So you want to click outside and then scroll the content of the iFrame

Comment: Yep. Let me see if VisioN's jQuery will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `iframe` is navigating in **your domain** then this code may help:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("iframe").contents().scrollTop(100);
});​
```

Otherwise, you will get an error saying something like "*Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame... Domains, protocols and ports must match*".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to scroll an iFrame from the outside. I do not know whether it works but how about trying to set the Hash of the iFrame to use the default scroll mechanism

```
$("iframe").attr("src", "http://www.example.com/#hash
```

where "hash" could be a name of an anchor or an id (the last works only in supporting browsers)

Edit 1: same domain you can simply set .scrollTop()

Answer (score 0):

The default scroll mechanism with the Hash works in most browsers, so it is the best solution for an iframe from an external domain.

Comment: Do you have an example?